# DH keypair exception in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, force.com, goinstant

I want to get access token of go instant api and I when I did this it send me following error

---

> 17:21:46:505 EXCEPTION_THROWN [10]|System.CalloutException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair

---

Please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue has been resolved.  It was due to a misconfiguration on our TLS endpoint that made it incompatible with Apex Callouts (and some Java versions).  I've confirmed Apex Callouts are once again working.

Comment: Yeeee!!! Its working now and I am building something magical and will show to world :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your SSL Library doesn't support 2048-bit DH parameters. Take a look at the BouncyCastle SSL Library as an alternative to what you're using. https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html If you continue to have problems after changing to BouncyCastle, please email us at support at goinstant.com so we can do a more in-depth debug of your problems.

re: https://developers.goinstant.com/v1/rest-api/authentication.html#comment-1397240856

Comment: In salesforce I am not able to check what ssl library they are using and what features are available in the Library they are using.

But one thing I can say is I have done thousands of Callouts with various external systems and never seen this problem except you.

I am not even find any expert who can explain how to solve this.

So please let me know how can I call your system via Rest Api from salesforce.

You are part of salesforce so I assume you are accessible from salesforce .

Please help me with this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, Support misunderstood that you were using Apex; I'm digging into the solution now.

Comment: Turns out we accidentally disabled ECDHE support on our TLS terminator; we should have this fixed shortly.  Your patience is appreciated and sorry once again for the confusion.